# Jdbctemplate connection pooling issue DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am using DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver in my spring boot application to connect to 6 different datasources along with JDBCTemplate.
However , while load testing with 100 or more threads I get an Pool is empty error.
As JDBCTemplate manages its own pool is there any other way to solve the error
Note : Each DB query takes around 3 minutes to execute fully
Below is the stack trace and DAO & other referenced classes.

```
application.properties
oms.db.datasource1.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx
oms.db.datasource1.username=xxxx
oms.db.datasource1.password=xxxx
oms.db.datasource1.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
oms.db.datasource1.schema=xxx 
(Muliple sources configured)

package com.att.first.oms.dataaccesslayer.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
 public class DataSourceConfig {

@Autowired
private OMSSegmentProperties omsSegmentProperties;

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource1")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource1")
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getSchema().get(0);
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getPassword());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getUsername());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getUrl());

    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource11")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource1")
public DataSource dataSource11() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getSchema().get(1);
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getPassword());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getUsername());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource1().getUrl());

    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource2")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getSchema().get(0);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource21")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource2")
public DataSource dataSource21() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getSchema().get(1);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource2().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource3")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource3")
public DataSource dataSource3() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getSchema().get(0);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource31")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource3")
public DataSource dataSource31() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getSchema().get(1);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource3().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource4")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource4")
public DataSource dataSource4() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getSchema().get(0);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource41")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource4")
public DataSource dataSource41() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getSchema().get(1);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource4().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource5")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource5")
public DataSource dataSource5() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getSchema().get(0);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource51")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource5")
public DataSource dataSource51() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getSchema().get(1);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource5().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource6")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource6")
public DataSource dataSource6() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getSchema().get(0);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource61")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oms.db.datasource6")
public DataSource dataSource61() {

    String SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="
            + this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getSchema().get(1);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    ds.setDriverClassName(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6()
            .getDriverClassName());
    ds.setUsername(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getPassword());
    ds.setUrl(this.omsSegmentProperties.getDatasource6().getUrl());
    ds.setInitSQL(SET_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    return ds;
}

@Bean
public DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver dataSource() {
    DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver resolver = new DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver();

    Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KC1A, dataSource1());
    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KC2, dataSource11());

    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KC5, dataSource2());
    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KC6, dataSource21());

    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KM3, dataSource3());
    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KM4, dataSource31());

    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KM5, dataSource4());
    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.KM6, dataSource41());

    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.STL1A, dataSource5());
    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.STL2, dataSource51());

    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.STL3, dataSource6());
    dataSources.put(OMSSegmentEnum.STL4, dataSource61());

    resolver.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1());
    resolver.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);

    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
}
```

And the calling class

```
@Repository
public class OMSGenericDAO {

private static final Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(OMSGenericDAO.class);

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<Object> fetch(String sql, Class clazz) {

    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

    log.info("Executing the query : " + sql);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(clazz));

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("List finished.Total no of records fetched ::" + result.size());
    log.info("Time to fetch" + (end - start) / 1000 + "seconds");

    return result;
}

public Object fetch(String sql, Class clazz, String... args) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, args, clazz);
}
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
: Got more than one input Future failure. Logging failures after the first
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-177-thread-3] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:289)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
at com.att.first.oms.dataaccesslayer.service.OMSGenericQueryServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae14cb26.fetch(<generated>)
at com.att.first.oms.dataaccesslayer.web.FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController.fetchFromSegment(FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController.java:64)
at com.att.first.oms.dataaccesslayer.web.FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController.access$000(FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController.java:28)
at com.att.first.oms.dataaccesslayer.web.FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController$1.call(FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController.java:81)
at com.att.first.oms.dataaccesslayer.web.FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController$1.call(FirstJavaOMSDataAccessController.java:79)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-177-thread-3] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:703)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:164)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:246)
... 17 more
```

Comment: Can you post the error ?

What size are your connection pools ?

Comment: @PaulNUK have added a stack trace. I spawned 200 threads at the same time to check .my issue is the 101 should wait until the pool is available

Comment: Can't you just increase maxWait on your tomcat connection pool settings ?

3 minutes a query ?!

Comment: @PaulNUK yes the query fetches a large dataset from 3rd party database , so we don't have any control on optimization w.r.t query.  I was looking for any optimizations w.r.t to code or any library , would commons dbcp be more efficient in handling sessions?@PaulNUK yes the query fetches a large dataset from 3rd party database , so we don't have any control on optimization w.r.t query.  I was looking for any optimizations w.r.t to code or any library ,commons dbcp be more efficient in handling sessions?I tried using the Annotation @ Transactional which did the trick no sure of its feasibility

Comment: It looks like you have connection leaks. It's odd that adding transactional helped as jdbcTemplate should close your connections anyway. Perhaps it was running in a higher transaction. Did you do requires new on your transactional annotation ?

Anyway, turn on logging for org.springframework and see when connections are getting closed with and without transactional, that's probably the clue you need.

Comment: @PaulNUK did not do a requires New.